# What do I call it when a word is "with the"?

Tags: meaning, terminology

[Wiktionary's definition of "open" as a noun](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/open#Noun) includes two that say:

> 1. *(with [the](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the))* Open or unobstructed space; an exposed location.
> 2. *(with [the](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the))* Public knowledge or scrutiny; full view.

**What is that "*(with the)*" called?** It's not a scope, is it?

Note that I know it means to use "open" with "the" before it, as in "the open". I'm asking what one would call that usage.

Comment: The dictionary is trying to use one definition to cover two uses of _open_. One is the attributive use _open sore, open door, open mind_; that's what they mean by "with the". An open sore is a sore  with open space, an open door is a door with open space, an open mind is a mind with open space. The other use is the predicative use, which means it's a predicate adjective. _The door/sore/mind is open_. No "with the" necessary. Dictionaries don't tell you about grammar; only special idioms.

Comment: @JohnLawler so, "attributive"?

Comment: @ Supuhstar: so, "question"?

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible to me.

Comment: You know how some Wiktionary definitions say "_(mathematics)_" before the actual definition? Well that's the scope, right? And some say "_(obsolete)_"? Well that's the prevalence, yeah? What's it called when it says "_(with the)_"?

Comment: @JohnLawler- The way I read the definition: (with the) literally means *when used with "the"* as in "the open".  for example *The men had nowhere to hide; they were out in **the open**.*  Which does indeed mean open or unobstructed space; an exposed position.  Similarly: *Snowden's actions put many secret projects out in **the open**.*   So to answer OP- I'd call it a **context specifier**.

Comment: The definite article has a characteristic of enhancing the meaning of a word that (usually unexpectedly) appears to be distinct from the usual, though in reality, it's just different way of looking at the concept. *cf.* **poor** *vs.* **the poor.** This phenomenon is well-recognized, though I do not know of a name for it. The phrase itself has no special name.

Comment: There's nothing special about _with the_. Sometimes a definition will say "with **some word**". It just means that the word being defined has a particular meaning when it's used in combination with that word

Comment: @JohnLawler - that is _not_ what the dictionary means. Both definitions are for the use of _open_ as a simple, independent _noun_, not used attributively at all. "The secret is out in _the open_" and "We camped in _the open_" are the two uses meant, and they are not attributive.

Comment: Whee, John's human. Mind you, I read (past tense) the situation the way he did too: their 'the' should be in quotes. Good spot, @Jim.

Comment: @Jim You should submit that as an answer :3

Comment: @oerkelens: Thanks. I didn't look at the dictionary entry. I just answered without context, which is the way the question was asked. That's what I usually do, because that's how most questions are asked here. That was my best guess, and it was wrong. Notice, however, that neither answer actually addresses the posed question: _What do I call it when a word is “with the”?_

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Rather than put "the" in quotes, they made it a link to the definition of "the". I guess they assumed that would make it clear that it's a reference to the word, rather than _with the_ being a special phrase of its own.

Comment: @Barmar So we need to add 'quotes should preserve hyperlinks and colour coding' to the list of rules!

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster refers to explanatory information that appears within a definition at the level of individual senses of the defined word as "an italicized label or guide phrase." Although the Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary's treatment of the noun *open* doesn't include "(*with the*)" or any other guide phrases, its handling of the adjective *open* includes several:

> **8 b** (2) *of a tone* **:** produced by an open string or on a wind instrument by the lip without the use of slides, valves or keys ... **11 a** (3)**:** *of a compound* : having components separated by a space in writing or printing ... **12 a** *of an organ pipe* **:** not stopped at the top **b** *of a string on a musical instrument* : not stopped by the finger ... **16** *of punctuation* **:** characterized by sparing use esp. of the comma **19** *of a universe* **:** having insufficient mass to halt expansion gravitationally

All of the italicized bits of the above block quotation are what MW calls "guide phrases." I suspect that the terminology is intentionally broad (and rather vague) to comprehend the many types of such explanatory information that a dictionary may need to use from time to time. In any case, Wiktionary's "(*with the*)" notation would certainly fall under the category of "guide phrase" in MW's terminology.

At another level, of course, you are free to call such explanatory information whatever you like. *Context specifier*, which Jim suggests in a comment beneath the poster's question, is one possibility; *usage limiter* and *phrasal prerequisite* and *scope definer* are others.

Comment: I've been tentatively using "specifier". Would that work, too?

Comment: I think a little more specificity helps, which is why I like Jim's two-word "context specifier." But I don't think that a relevant, widely accepted term exists, so you're free to use whatever wording you like best. Still, it's probably a good idea to define what you mean by your favored term the first time you use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can call *the* the grammatical context for that particular sense of **open**. You'd say that sense X of **open** is of restricted distribution, and that the use of sense X requires a definite article in the noun phrase containing **open**. *The* doesn't have to strictly precede **open**, though. (You can say 'the great wide open.')

Comment: so, a "Grammatical context"?

Comment: @Supuhstar yeah, that's my answer. the term is more general than the specific case you bring up. 'context' in linguistics usually means the words, word-parts, sounds, etc., that reliably appear with some target usage.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a *qualifier*, as it qualifies the definition to say that it only applies in the specified scope.

Comment: A qualifier does not bring in a new meaning that is distinct from or at variance with the original.

Comment: It's not distinct, it's a refinement or limitation.

Answer (score 0):

*(With the)* simply means that the specified meaning of the noun *open* applies *only* when the definite article *the* is used. For example, the last meaning is used in the sentence *the secret was out in the open*. You can **not** use *an open* here.

A specific name for the "with the" construction that this specific dictionary uses, I don't know, but basically, both uses are *idiomatic*, which restricts the use to very specific contexts.

That said, the first definition (as in *Australian Open*), I can hardly imagine with an indefinite article (He won three *Opens*, really?). Only the second one (He found the open in the circuit_) would sound all right as *he found an open in the circuit*, but that is almost exclusively jargon.

Comment: "open in the circuit" is not even jargon, it's plain ham/ignorant phrasing, because 'open' in that domain is short for 'open circuit.'

Comment: @Kris - blame wiktionary :) I didn't mean to pretend I knew anything about electrotechnical jargon.

Comment: @Kris So you mean the sentence is short for _He found an open circuit in the circuit_ ? That doesn't sound right. In this context, _open_ refers to the break that causes the circuit to be open.

Comment: @Barmar Precisely what I meant: "That doesn't sound right." It's just not right. Read my comment again.

Comment: And one up voter to the comment, too: What is the "break" that causes the circuit to open called?

Comment: so... what do you _call_ it?

Comment: @Supuhstar - nothing more than a _usage description_. You are looking for a word that describes "with egg" in the phrase "This dough is made with egg". You could called it an _isolated, forwarded adverbial clause_ if you want (word x is used _with the_). In short, why are you so bothered by a possible name for it? Why do you _want_ to name it so dearly? It is a description of how to use the word. So it is a usage description. Just like "word X is used in situation A", or "doing the X" is _idiomatic_.